# Keyboard libraries or simple code?

Tags: firmware, keyboard

I am in research for building a custom keyboard using an Arduino or Teensy microcontroller. Concerning the programming of the M/C I have come across firmware libraries such as [**tmk** or **qmk**](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/master/docs/faq_general.md).

Yet I wonder, why not write some simple Arduino Wiring code such as:

https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-keyboard-matrix-tutorial.html

What are the benefits of using a library instead of a simple code in which the press of a switch will be detected and an additional signal will be sent via USB?

Benefits on speed, flexibility or anything else?

**P.S.** I am not sure if this answer belongs here. Feel free to migrate it to Stack Overflow or Arduino Stack Exchange.

Comment: Usually because using a "library" is tested/documented code you drop into your solution, whereas "rolling your own" is prone to bugs and takes longer. They also usually include features you may have trouble writing or didn't think to implement.

Comment: On the other hand, libraries are often overly simplistic and don't play well with others library code you later use as you grow in skill. It may be better to focus on developing deep skills in keyboard scanning that will serve you well later on. What's better depends on how far you intend to go with this.

Comment: When it takes longer to figure out how to interface the library with my code, and/or it turns out to not do what I want, I write my own code from scratch. And when the  FAQ doesn't even tell me what it does I stay away from it.